# How many Gribnoe Lukoshko tomato plants are suggested for 1 person?

Tags: tomatoes

When speaking about plants per person you see a list of plants suggested per person, but how many [Gribnoe Lukoshko](http://www.friendsschoolplantsale.com/plant/8990) tomato plants are suggested per person when wanting to ensure there's plenty for you to eat, and make salsa with?

Comment: How many tomatoes / kg of tomatoes would you need? “Plenty” can be quite different things, depending on whom you ask. And what makes you think that the yield would be different from other tomato cultivars of similar size?

Comment: On a very personal note: I suggest you phrase your question a bit more “user friendly” - in this case, simply adding that you are talking about tomatoes helps. Not everyone is willing to follow a link just to understand a question. (BTW, we have a few users that are quite interested and knowledgeable in tomatoes and it may help getting their attention if you actually mention “tomatoes”.)

Comment: the statistical average, and it yields like a big zac with bulges instead of cracks